# MVC3 & Razor: How to structure forms & actions to allow for postback-like functionality?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with a drop down list.  The default value for this is stored in a session variable.  However, the user change change this, in which case new data is entered.

I have a change handler on the drop down:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, 
                        new SelectList(Model.SelectValues, "Key", "Value",
                        Model.SelectedID), "", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" });

 ... more fields ...
 <input type="submit" name="Save" />
}

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(ViewModel vm)
  {
     ... decide if I update my data or save the changes ...
  }
```

I tried wrapping the select in a separate form tag, but then the value of my SelectedID not updated in my view model.

How can I determine when the form is posted from a drop down change, and when it is posted from a button click?

Comment: you are offering two paths for submitting data?

Comment: @Brian: Basically.  One is to change the filter, the other is to update the filtered data.

Comment: would jquery and ajax be an option?  basically you could use the select list on change to fire a jquery post that calls a method from your controller which returns what you need and re-writes it without doing a postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to reload the entire page when the user changes the selection of the dropdown you could use AJAX to silently trigger a request to a different controller action that will do the necessary updates. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedID, 
    new SelectList(Model.SelectValues, "Key", "Value"), 
    "", 
    new { 
        id = "myddl",
        data_url = Url.Action("update")
    }
)
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myddl').change(function() {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(), 
            success: function() {
                alert('update success');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and finally you could have a controller action responsible for the update:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ViewModel vm)
{
    ... this will be triggered everytime the user changes some value in the
        droipdown list
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to reload the page - there is a large amount of data in the form.

Comment: The entire page or only some portion? If it is some portion you could return a partial from the Update controller action and then refresh the corresponding placeholder in the AJAX success callback.

Comment: I was thinking the entire page, but may have to rethink that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to simply attach some behavior to those element's events and set a hidden field with the event target (which by now, should sound very familiar to `__EVENTTARGET`).

Like so:

```
$('#someButton').click(function()
{
    $('#someHiddenField').val('someButton');
});

$('#someDropDown').change(function()
{
   $('#someHiddenField').val('someDropDown');
});
```

And then your action method could inspect this value and act appropriately.

**HOWEVER**

It sounds like you're thinking in an outmoded concept for MVC. If you really needed some new information, you should consider using some Ajax and then having one of your action methods return a partial view if you want to update part of the page.